# Counting the number of Nodes in Binary Tree O(logn)^2

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, big-o

I have a question in which I need to find the number of nodes in a complete tree in time complexity of
`O((log(n))^2`)  e.g. (log of n )^2 , my go was
to find `h` which is `h= log n` (the height of the tree, moving always left as it is a complete tree) and then come to each node at `h-1` and check if it has a right node, if it has, then it must have a left node (because of complete tree) if it doesn't then check if it has a left node and just like that count the number of nodes.

The problem is that I think it is `O(n)` because `h = log(n)` and the number of nodes in this height is `2^(h-1)` and so this whole process is `O(n)` and not `O( (log n)^2)`  ..

The output of
[image: This tree]
is 12 as it has 12 nodes , in time complexity of O( (log n)^2)

I would appreciate help please! thank you.

Comment: You can perform binary search where the items in the last row stop, then do the math about the number of nodes.

Comment: maybe you could somehow combine it with binary search (as you know that it is a complete tree)...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is it a binary search for each node in the h-1 row? (not the last row)?

Comment: @StackOMeow: you simply binary search at what node at the `h-1` row, the nodes no longer have two subchildren.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so for each node at `h-1` I perform a binary search and thus, because `h= log n` and binary search takes up `log n` then for each node in height we perform `log n` so it's `log n * log n` am I correct ?

Comment: @StackOMeow: exactly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The problem is to write an algorithm that does this (in words or pseudo code) because binary search in array is using indexes (numbers, mid = left + righ t /2 ) but here we don't have indexes

Comment: @StackOMeow: well here you now that the root node (approximately) splits the tree in half. So you can look if the leftmost child of the right subtree is filled, if not, you can "descend" to the left subtree (since we know the bottom row stops at that subchild), if not we descend on the right subtree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael told you have to somehow to apply binary search in your problem. 
So the easiest way to do it to go by this algorythm:

1. First, as you said, we have to find the height of a tree, to do this we just go streight to leftmost node;
2. As we know the height H of the tree, now we can apply the binary search:
3. I'll describe the algorythm for the root, which is the same for every next node:

   **Every time we search the most left leaf of the right subtree.**

   So if there is a leaf on the height H, as in the picture, then repeat procedure with the right child(find the left most leaf of the right subtree of the tree where "root" is Node C).

   If there is no leaf, then repeat the same procedure with left child of the root.

As we see, every time we cut the problem by the factor of 2. 
So the complexity would be H * (amount of searches) = log n * log n[image]

Comment: this algorithm only returns the number of nodes in the last level (height H) right? because we know that the number of nodes = nodes in height H + 2^(h-1) -1

Comment: Yes, you are right. We know the full amount of nodes on the Height: H - 1, as you wrote, so we have to count the amount of nodes on the last level.

Comment: I am confused, about the algorithm, let's say we are at F it has a left child , L and not a right child so we can stop right here, and not move to the left sub-tree like your algorithm suggests, no?

Comment: It is the matter of taste. For my opinion it is easier to stop when we are on the leaf level, so we just have to check wheather left and right nodes are nulls and we are here. But again, it is up to you when to stop.

Comment: But in your algorithm you say that if we don't have a leaf in height H then we do the same thing for the left sub tree but it won't end forever, because let's say you check: L is a leaf on height H : fine , then do the same thing for the right sub tree- is G a leaf on height H? no then go to the left most leaf of the left sub tree of A  so -  node J , but then, why? if we found that G does not have children and F does have only one, then of course E and D will have children .. what is the stop if statement of the algorithm, when do we stop?

Comment: Ok let's go through the picture and try to find out when to stop:

1) Go to the left most leaf of the right subtree of the root - leaf L, ok go to the right, minus 1 level, we are on the node C.
2) Go to the left most leaf of the right subtree of the root - no leaf, then go to the left, minus 1 level again, and we are on the node F.
3) Go to the left most leaf of the right subtree of the root - no leaf, then go to the left, minus 1 level again, and we are on the leaf level.
So we can't go futher, we reached the end.The main is that we can't go up, only down.

Comment: But what do we accumulate while we recursively iterate as your algorithm suggets? if it has a node then return 1 + sameFunction(tree.Right) ? and if it does not then we return sameFunction(tree.left) ( 0 + sameFunction(tree.left) but it's the same)

Comment: I didn't tald that algorythm should be implemented recursively, you could implement it iteratively, but.
If you want it implement recursively you shoud pass bounderies in the call of the function.
You reach the end when the bounderies will be equal, so you have to return this number.
You shouldn't summ anything, just adjust bounderies.

Comment: The problem is that you said `go to the right, minus 1 level, we are on the node C` but then at the end `The main is that we can't go up, only down.` so how do you get up to C ?

Comment: I ment that go to the right - it is minus 1 level from root(the same is to the left), nothing more. So if we go from root to the right - we go down on one level - to the node C.

Comment: I am still having a hard time thinking about your algorithm, what is the pseudo code? I don't understand how you can traverse from L to C .. I would appreciate your help writing the pseudo-code.. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213607/discussion-between-ivan-lapunka-and-stackomeow).

Answer (score 2):

First, count the distance to the leftmost leaf by traversing `left` pointers. Then do the same with `right` pointers. If both numbers are `n`, then you have a perfect tree  with 2^n - 1 nodes.

Otherwise, they're not equal. Then the first count was some number `n+1` and the second was `n`.  We need to probe - with binary search as others have said - the complete `n`-deep layer of nodes (counting the root as layer 1) to find the leftmost that has either 0 or 1 children.  There are 2^(n-1) nodes to probe. In the example, n=3, so we're probing 4 nodes.

We can probe that layer by considering the bits in the numbers 0..2^(n-1) - 1.  In the example, this is 0..3 (which is n-2 bits).  In a traversal from root to leaf, a 0 bit means "go left." A 1 means "go right."  For a reason discussed below, you want to use the bits from highest to lowest-order (in the example, bits 1,0) from root toward leaves. It's not hard to see that using 0..2^(n-1) - 1 as path traversal "instructions," you'll get to every vertex in that layer from left to right. For example, 2 has bits 10. That means start at the root, go right then left, which takes you to F.

But of course you don't want to search each vertex in the n-deep layer, since that would make your search O(n). Instead, use binary search. First try the "instruction" at the midpoint of [0..2^(n-1) - 1].  If you find 2 children, then reduce the search bracket to values greater than the midpoint.  If you find 0 children, then values less. Continue in this manner until you've either found a node with 1 child or the bracket is size 1 and there are 0 children. The latter means you've found the leftmost node in the layer with no children.

Now we can find the total number of children easily. The part of the tree down to layer n has 2^(n-1) - 1 nodes, and the "instruction" that got you to the final search node tells you how many nodes there are in layer n+1.  Together, these tell you the final answer. I'll let you work out the final details.